# Dictionary form of the word "её"

Tags: морфология, словообразование

I am doing some coding to retrieve the dictionary forms of Russian words. It generally seems to be working reasonably well, but for the word "её", it leaves it unchanged instead of changing it to "она". I've tried two different programmes with similar results.

In the first (pymystem3), if I try it with only the word "её", it does give me the correct "она", but if it's in a sentence, it returns "ее".

In the second (pymorphy2), it gives "её" on both occasions. If I try the same with e.g. "его", I get the correct "он".

It made me wonder if this is some kind of a glitch with the programmes I'm using or if I'm missing something about the word "её"?

Comment: Do you mean you think _она_ is the only correct dictionary form of _её_? In fact, _её_ has 2 meanings, there are 2 homonyms: 1. Genitive and Accusative case of the 3rd p. feminine personal pronoun _она_ (Я видел _её_ - “I saw _her_”) – here the dictionary form is _она_; 2. 3rd p. sg. feminine possessive pronoun, indeclinable (_её_ отец - “_her_ father”) – here the dictionary form is _её_. To tell the two homonyms from each other one needs to do syntactic analysis of the text, mere search through a word-list is not enough.

Comment: Besides, _её_ is often written as _ее_, in the standard Russian orthography the two dots over _ё_ is optional and can be freely omitted. A good dictionary will have the dots, but you know, things happen.

Comment: Thanks, @YellowSky, I forgot about the second dictionary form!

Answer (score 2):

её = her in all the senses, same as in English

I see **her** = Я вижу **её**

**Her** father = **Её** отец

Answer (score 0):

Она means she.
**She** is a very sweet person. **Она** очень милый человек.

When we talk about «она», we don’t say об она, we say о **ней**. Same with if you are with her. С **ней**.
I think **about her**. Я думаю **о ней**.
I was with her. Я была **с ней**.

But there’s **ей** and **её**. Её, basically it means her in all senses. Kind of like меня is me, тебя и вас are you, and его is him or it (оно). Ей is to her.

Her hat is blue. **Её** шапка синяя.
I love her. Я **её** люблю.
She is 20 years old. **Ей** 20 лет.
I gave it to her. Я **ей** дала.

The dictionary form by default is она.